# How to determine cancel dates based on effective dates on DB2 for i?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to set cancel dates based on finding the next effective date and subtracting one day to determine the previous row's expiration. I have multiple items uniquely keyed by item and effective date (ACEFF) and I want to reverse-engineer the "desired" (expiration) date, column ACCAN from the "Effective" dates.  The newest item will have an empty expiration date.

| Key | Effective | (desired) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 01/01/2023 | 01/31/2023 |
| A1 | 02/01/2023 | 02/28/2023 |
| A1 | 03/01/2023 |  |
| A2 | 01/01/2023 | 01/15/2023 |
| A2 | 01/16/2023 | 01/31/2023 |
| A2 | 02/01/2023 |  |

This code (originally from this site IIRC) should, but doesn't work consistently (in some cases, it incorrectly propagates one exipiration date across a multiple rows).

```
UPDATE frp011i a
    SET a.accan = IFNULL((SELECT b.aceff - 1 DAY
                        FROM frp011i b
                        WHERE a.accust = b.accust
                          AND a.ackey  = b.ackey
                          AND a.actc   = b.actc
                          AND a.aceff  < b.aceff
                          AND a.accan  = '0001-01-01' FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY),'0001-01-01')
    WHERE a.accan = '0001-01-01' 
    ORDER BY a.accust,a.ackey,a.actc,a.aceff DESC WITH NC
```

Statement logic: for each row ("a") with no expiration date, look for a row ("b") in the same group (identical keys except for the effective date) with an *earlier* effective date, and then make the "a" row's expiration date one day before "b"'s effective date.

The derived expiration dates are reset before testing.  There are no duplicate rows.  The expiration date is not a key.  There are no duplicate copies of the table.  The execution environment is stable and unremarkable.  The execution and error logs are clean.  There are no allocation or record lock errors.

Thanks for your help.

Unexpected results, usually in the form of an unrelated date bring applied as the expiration date.  The script log shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using `merge` and `lead(...) over(...)` (works in DB2 for I 7.3)

```
create table table1 (key char(2), effective date, cancel date)
```

```
insert into table1 (key, effective)
  VALUES
  ('A1', date '2023-01-01'),
  ('A1', '2023-02-01'),
  ('A1', '2023-03-01'),
  ('A2', '2023-01-01'),
  ('A2', '2023-01-16'),
  ('A2', '2023-02-01')
```

```
select * from table1
```

| KEY | EFFECTIVE | CANCEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2023-01-01 | *null* |
| A1 | 2023-02-01 | *null* |
| A1 | 2023-03-01 | *null* |
| A2 | 2023-01-01 | *null* |
| A2 | 2023-01-16 | *null* |
| A2 | 2023-02-01 | *null* |

```
select
  key,
  effective,
  lead(effective) over(partition by key order by effective) - 1 day as cancel
from table1
```

| KEY | EFFECTIVE | CANCEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-31 |
| A1 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| A1 | 2023-03-01 | *null* |
| A2 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-15 |
| A2 | 2023-01-16 | 2023-01-31 |
| A2 | 2023-02-01 | *null* |

```
merge into table1 using (
  select
    key,
    effective,
    lead(effective) over(partition by key order by effective) - 1 day as cancel
  from table1
) as a on (table1.key, table1.effective) = (a.key, a.effective)
when matched then update set cancel = a.cancel
```

```
select * from table1
```

| KEY | EFFECTIVE | CANCEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-31 |
| A1 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| A1 | 2023-03-01 | *null* |
| A2 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-15 |
| A2 | 2023-01-16 | 2023-01-31 |
| A2 | 2023-02-01 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aC1ZDi2s)